# Built-in functions take more execution time than user defined functions? (Python)

Tags: python, function, time-complexity

```py
import time

startTime = time.time()

def oddList(arr):

  a=[]

  for element in arr:

    if element%2 == 0:

      a.append(element)

    return a
    
arr = [i for i in range(8)]

for i in range(1000000):

  odd = (list(filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0,arr)))

  # odd = oddList(arr)
        
    
endTime = time.time()

print(endTime - startTime, "utilizing the in-built method")
```

*If I use the user defined function `oddList`, then why does it take less time than the in-built function? I can't understand why it's happening as both are doing the same thing.*

[User-defined function](https://i.ibb.co/7pYxWkL/Screenshot-79-LI.jpg)

[In-built function](https://i.ibb.co/cbBCMpZ/Screenshot-80-LI.jpg)

Comment: By "inbuilt function" are you referring to `filter` and `list`?

Comment: Just curious - why do you call your function `oddList` when you're making a list of the *even* numbers? That's what `element % 2 == 0` does...

Comment: @MattDMo - that's what makes it odd

Comment: @tdelaney I see what you did there

Comment: sorry for the wrong function name but my question is about execution time so it will not matter I am building an odd list or an even list

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `filter` calls the `lambda` function for each comparison. That means that a new function object and stack frame need to be constructed just to test `x%2`. Its the difference between (call function, compare, return result, compare result) verses (compare). A third way is to use a list comprehension. Reworking your test a bit

```
import time

def oddList(arr):
    a=[]
    for element in arr:
        if element%2:
            a.append(element)
    return a

arr=[i for i in range(8)]

startTime = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    odd=(list(filter(lambda x: x%2,arr)))
print("filter", time.time()-startTime)

startTime = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    odd=oddList(arr)
print("function", time.time()-startTime)

startTime = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    odd=[n for n in arr if n%2]
endTime=time.time()
print("comprehension", time.time() - startTime)
```

I got

```
filter 0.7806670665740967
function 0.5075747966766357
comprehension 0.43089747428894043
```

The list comprehension wins.